# making POST request with form-data using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, httprequest, httpurlconnection

I need to make a POST request to an external API using HttpURLConnection. POST request involves form-data in body part. When the request is made with Postman i am able to choose the form-data under body section. How do i achieve this with Java code

```
connection = connectionURL.openConnection();

HashMap<String,String> hashmap = new HashMap<String,String>();
hashmap.put("JSONObject","{name:\"Contact from Java\"}");

//Set request method 
((HttpURLConnection) connection).setRequestMethod("POST");

//Set request headers 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "authtoken");

connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
writer.writeBytes(hashmap.toString());

writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Edited code

```
    connection = connectionURL.openConnection();

    HashMap<String,String> hashmap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hashmap.put("JSONString","{name:\"Contact from Java\"}");

    //Set request method 
    ((HttpURLConnection) connection).setRequestMethod("POST");

    //Set request headers 
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-url-encoded;charset=UTF-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "authtoken");

    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    writer.writeBytes(hashmap.toString());

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

This is the request i'm trying to do with Java
[image: This is the request i'm trying to do with Java]
and here is my response

[image]

What is my mistake ?thanks in advance

Comment: you are passing "JSONObject" instead of "JSONString" as key

Comment: same response after correcting that mistake and including application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 

will JSONString be sent as form-data when i use writeBytes of the stream

Comment: look at the api docs, there is no "name" field. Replace it with contact_name?